# Variable length array of non-POD element type 'set<int>'

Tags: c++

I have no idea what the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile("meeting.in");
    int FF, NumPaths;
    infile >> FF >> NumPaths;
    int Paths[NumPaths][4];
    set<int> Bessie_Times[FF];
    set<int> Elsie_Times[FF];
    for(int i=0;i<NumPaths;i++)
    {
        infile >> Paths[i][0] >> Paths[i][1] >> Paths[i][2] >> Paths[i][3];
    }
    sort(Paths,Paths+NumPaths);
}
```

At these lines, I get these errors:

```
    int Paths[NumPaths][4];
```

> Array type 'int[4]' is not assignable

```
    set<int> Bessie_Times[FF];
```

> Error 1: Array initializer must be an initializer list
>
> Error 2: variable length array of non-POD element type 'set'

Does anyone know what is causing this? I have researched around, but could not seem to find anything that resolved the problem. I assume I am trying to use a variable type where I shouldn't be, but I cannot find an instance of this.

Comment: VLAs are non-standard anyway, I would suggest using a `std::vector<std::set<int>>`.

Answer (score 3):

g++ compile your code fine(except sort). I don't know is that violates standard or not. But anyway in c++ you should use containers from stdlib:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream infile("meeting.in");
  int FF, NumPaths;
  infile >> FF >> NumPaths;

  std::vector<array<int, 4>> Paths(FF);
  std::vector<set<int>> Bessie_Times(FF);
  std::vector<set<int>> Elsie_Times(FF); 

  for(int i = 0; i < NumPaths; i++)
  {
    infile >> Paths[i][0] >> Paths[i][1] >> Paths[i][2] >> Paths[i][3];    
  }  

  sort(Paths.begin(), Paths.end());

  return 0;
}
```

Not sure about sorting; maybe you need to add

```
sort(Paths[i].begin(), Paths[i].end());
```

inside loop

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int Paths[NumPaths][4];//Array type 'int[4]' is not assignable
> ```

You are attempting to statically declare an array with a length not known at compile-time, but only known at run-time.  You cannot do this as C++ does not allow it.  You can, however, dynamically declare an array of which length is known at run-time:

```
int Paths[NumPaths][4]; // wrong

int *Paths[4]; // right
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  Paths[i] = new int[NumPaths];
```

> ```
> set<int> Bessie_Times[FF];//Error 1: Array initializer must be an initializer list Error 2: variable length array of non-POD element type 'set<int>'`
> ```

Likewise, this becomes:

```
set<int> Bessie_Times[FF]; // wrong
set<int> *Bessie_Times = new set<int>[FF]; // right
```

Note that you must remember to deallocate all dynamic memory at the end of your program:

```
delete Paths[][];
delete BessieTimes[];
```

Comment: It seems that you got indices backwards.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, you need to delete all Paths[i]. You really ought to be using vectors and/or smart pointers for this though.

Comment: I would upvote this for noting VLAs aren't Standard C++ and that `new` must be matched with `delete`, but then I would have to downvote it for not mentioning that `new` and `delete` should almost never be used in end-user C++ code. :/ Otherwise we might as well all keep using C, slowly patching endless memory leaks one by one, for the rest of time. The OP is already using `std::set`, so the real answer is right next-door: stop manually allocating arrays and just use `std::vector`.